# Is there a way to set the upload folder in the backend? TYPO3 v11.5

Tags: file, file-upload, directory, typo3, tca

I want to restrict/change/set access to a specific file folder when uploading to a file field from the backend.

I have the following TCA code from the upload file field:

```
'document' => [
    'label' => 'Label',
    'description'   => 'Description',
    'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
        'document',
        [
            'minitems' => 1,
            'maxitems' => 1,
            'appearance' => [
                'fileUploadAllowed' => false,
            ],
        ], 'pdf'
    )
],
```

I don't know if there is some kind of option to set the folder for the upload files field, something like:

```
'folder' => '/fileadmin/myfolder',
```

Comment: Since TYPO3 v12.3 via page TSconfig: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/12.4/en-us/PageTsconfig/Options.html#pagedefaultuploadfolder

Also via user TSconfig (in older and newer versions): https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/12.4/en-us/UserTsconfig/Options.html#useroptions-defaultuploadfolder

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with some TSconfig https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/12.4/en-us/PageTsconfig/Options.html#pagedefaultuploadfolder but this does not have all functionalities https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/default_upload_folder has